# C++ constexpr count constructor calls

Tags: c++, instantiation, constexpr

I'm trying to static instantiate some objects at compile time. What I need is to set to a member int variable an incremented value. For example, the first object I create will have the 0 value, the second 1, the third 2...
Summarizing I need something like this but it has to work as constexpr.

```
//header
class MyClass final {
private:
    static int IDcount;
public:
    const int ID;
    constexpr MyClass(args);
    //~MyClass();
};
//source
int MyClass::IDcount = 0;
constexpr MyClass::MyClass(args) : ID(MyClass::IDcount++) {
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this at compile time (without taking the ID as argument of the constructor)

Comment: No, you are out of luck, as you rely on program-state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done the way you've defined it, but there is a non-standard but widely implemented preprocessor trick that could be employed.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass final {
    constexpr MyClass(int myid, const char *myname)
        : id(myid), name(myname) {}
    int id;
    const char *name;
};

constexpr MyClass m[]{ 
    MyClass(__COUNTER__, "Larry"),
    MyClass(__COUNTER__, "Moe"),
    MyClass(__COUNTER__, "Curly")
};

int main()
{
    for (auto const &obj : m)
        std::cout << obj.id << '\t' << obj.name << "\n";
}
```

The `__COUNTER__` macro is defined in [Microsoft's Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), [gcc since version 4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).

When run, this program produces:

```
0   Larry
1   Moe
2   Curly
```

Answer (score 3):

A `constexpr`-function or ctor must be a valid core constant expression on at least one path:

> #### 7.1.5 The constexpr specifier `[dcl.constexpr]`
>
> 5 For a non-template, non-defaulted `constexpr` function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting `constexpr` constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Which means it cannot modify a global object on all paths:

> #### 5.19 Constant expressions `[expr.const]`
>
> 2. A *conditional-expression* `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
>    - modification of an object (5.17, 5.2.6, 5.3.2) unless it is applied to a non-volatile lvalue of literal type
>        that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;